# python change 3d array from MxNxN into NxNxM

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, 3d, numpy-ndarray

Hello, I want to ask a question about how to change the dimension order(?).

I have 75x120x120 (AxBxC) ( I am trying to save the array to .mat file), and I want to make it as 120x120x75 (BxCxA).

Please kindly give me a suggestion on this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use reshape function for the same... 
For simplicity,I took the dimensions to be smaller but surely it will serve the purpose

```
arr = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]]])
arr.shape
>> (2,3,3)
arr = np.reshape(arr,(3,3,2))
arr.shape
>> (3,3,2)
```

Hope it will help you out.